# How to detect if a server is overloaded on Linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, high-load

I would like to develop a "simple" script which should be automatically detect (every 5 minutes let say) if a server (in this case the same host on which it is running) is overloaded or not.

The server in question hosts a Web server (Apache) and a MySQL server.

I found some interesting resources related to this problem:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029043/know-if-a-mysql-server-is-overloaded-with-php
2. http://spicefuse.com/server-overloading-explained-t-2.html
3. http://linux.die.net/man/3/overload

It's clear that before stating that a server is overloaded or not I should check several parameters, but how can I combine them? Which are the thresholds for each of these aspects?

In your opinion, what would be the "best" solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your end goal in knowing the server is under high load?

Comment: Only you can answer these questions based on your workloads and business requirements.

Answer (score 3):

A server is overloaded when it cannot perform it's required functions in a timely manner.  What counts as "required functions" and "timely manner" is defined by the person(s) responsible for the machine's operation, in consultation with the stakeholders of the service(s) provided.

Comment: Yuck for the word stakeholders.  I've been hearing it far too often at work recently.  Otherwise, agreed.

Comment: Would you rather be a steakholder?